# Box2D: How to listen to bodies added to or remove from world?

Tags: box2d, box2dweb

In Box2D how can I listen to bodies added to or remove from world? I want to use them for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such features in Box2D. For joints and fixtures there are 'destruction listeners', which are there for convenience because destroying one body can cause multiple joints and fixtures to be destroyed. But for bodies, each call to DestroyBody will only ever destroy a single body, and you know where the DestroyBody calls are, so you might as well place any 'listener' type processing in the same place.

I guess you could wrap the DestroyBody calls like this:

```
// before
world->DestroyBody( body );

// after
myDestroyBody( world, body );

// where myDestroyBody is
void myDestroyBody( b2World* world, b2Body* body ) {
    ... do processing for body about to be destroyed ...
    world->DestroyBody( body );        
}
```

If this seems like it doesn't really achieve much, that's because it doesn't :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to have an array, at all times, of all your bodies.

Just compare the array to itself at each frame. There: you know what's added, and what's destroyed.